# PFQueryTableView Cell segues to Multiple DetailView

Tags: ios, ios7, storyboard, parse-platform, detailview

Ok so what I'm trying to do is after the user selects a cell it will show a PFImageView loaded from the same class. (All set there)

What I can't manage to do is to show more images. I want to use the swipe gesture to go from one image to the next. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You need to add a swipe gesture recognizer to the PFImageView, and then in the handler you get the next object and display the corresponding image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who needs help on this: a related question was answered.

[Related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/captcha?s=439c9cdd-a33b-437c-9294-fa8e3f74e3d5)